# VS Code is ignoring my tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've added a TypeScript setting to settings.json:

```
{"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"}
```

But for some reason VS Code is now (I think) ignoring the tsconfig.json file in my project. For example, it tells me to set "experimentalDecorators", but I have this set in my tsconfig, and it isn't picking up on other TypeScript definitions I've added to the tsconfig.

Answer (score -2):

- Make sure you have a single tsconfig.json
- Restart VSCode.